# Как получать несколько фото в одном хендлере Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Собственно вопрос, есть некий хендлер который ловит в себя фото(сжатые) и к примеру пересылает куда-то там.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.PHOTO)
async def send_to_admin(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=ADMIN_ID, photo=message.photo[-1].file_id)
```

Так вот если этот юзер(который присылает боту фото) пришлет не одно а два и более, и они буду группированы вот так.

[image: вот так]

То возникает странная ситуация, хендлер реагирует на каждое отдельное фото, собственно отдельно. По факту он срабатывает дважды (по 1-му на фото), то есть наша `message.photo` имеет только вариации одной из фоток (размеры) но не имеет другого фото в себе.

Потому вернусь к вопросу, есть ли способ ловить эту "группу" одним хендлером? Ведь есть же способ отправлять группу фото, должен же быть способ и получать их "группой"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите [это](https://github.com/WhiteMemory99/aiogram_album_handler/blob/master/example/album.py), должно помочь

```
import asyncio
from typing import List, Union

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import CancelHandler
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware

bot = Bot(token="TOKEN_HERE")  # Place your token here
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


class AlbumMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    """This middleware is for capturing media groups."""

    album_data: dict = {}

    def __init__(self, latency: Union[int, float] = 0.01):
        """
        You can provide custom latency to make sure
        albums are handled properly in highload.
        """
        self.latency = latency
        super().__init__()

    async def on_process_message(self, message: types.Message, data: dict):
        if not message.media_group_id:
            return

        try:
            self.album_data[message.media_group_id].append(message)
            raise CancelHandler()  # Tell aiogram to cancel handler for this group element
        except KeyError:
            self.album_data[message.media_group_id] = [message]
            await asyncio.sleep(self.latency)

            message.conf["is_last"] = True
            data["album"] = self.album_data[message.media_group_id]

    async def on_post_process_message(self, message: types.Message, result: dict, data: dict):
        """Clean up after handling our album."""
        if message.media_group_id and message.conf.get("is_last"):
            del self.album_data[message.media_group_id]


@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.ANY)
async def handle_albums(message: types.Message, album: List[types.Message]):
    """This handler will receive a complete album of any type."""
    media_group = types.MediaGroup()
    for obj in album:
        if obj.photo:
            file_id = obj.photo[-1].file_id
        else:
            file_id = obj[obj.content_type].file_id

        try:
            # We can also add a caption to each file by specifying `"caption": "text"`
            media_group.attach({"media": file_id, "type": obj.content_type})
        except ValueError:
            return await message.answer("This type of album is not supported by aiogram.")

    await message.answer_media_group(media_group)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dp.middleware.setup(AlbumMiddleware())
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Вот ещё вариант.

Так мы сможем сохранять полученные фото в БД. Способ загрузки не будет иметь значение, хоть альбомом, хоть по одному. Ну и есть возможность работать с несколькими пользователями одновременно, грех не использовать асинхронность.

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from create_bot import dp,bot
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from Keyboards import client_kb
from Data_base import sqlite_db
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton


List_photo = {}


class FSMReport(StatesGroup):
    city = State()
    address = State()
    photo = State()

       
async def report_photo(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
    global List_photo
    key = str(message.from_user.id)
    List_photo.setdefault(key, [])
    if message.content_type == 'photo':
        List_photo[key].append(message.photo[0].file_id)            
    elif message.content_type == 'text':
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['photo'] = ','.join(List_photo[key])
            List_photo.pop(key)
        await sqlite_db.sql_add_photo_report(state)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Готово', reply_markup=client_kb.kb_client)
        await state.finish()


def register_handlers_client(dp: Dispatcher):        
    dp.register_message_handler(report_photo, content_types=['photo', 'text'], state=FSMReport.photo)
```

**РЕЗУЛЬТАТ:**
[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видим в списке по ключу data['photo'], количество id, равных количеству фото. И загружались они не по одной.

Comment: Это не решает вопроса. Вопрос состоит в том чтобы в моменте иметь в контейнере(списке) все фото, которые юзер отправил боту. Просто ловить фотки по одной, можно и простым хендлером с нужным контен_тайпом.

Comment: @oleksandrigo добавил в ответ результат. Как по мне так в моменте, мы как раз имеем все фотки, которые отправлены боту. Или я всё же неправильно понял суть самого вопроса?

Comment: За выходные появилась мысль. Возможно дело в том, какой версией приложения пользоваться, десктопной или мобильной. И, если дело в этом, то да, мой вариант под десктопное приложение не подходит.

Comment: нет, оно то работает, но в целом ваш ответ делает почти то же что и мой только без привязки по времени, ну и подтверждением  отправки. Думаю тоже не плохой вариант, но не совсем ответ, скорее хороший способ.

Answer (score -1):

```
TOKEN = "1234646854fdghdfhfghfghssfhhgh"

def send_group_img(chat_id, text):
    temp_files_list = list()
    media = list()
    files = dict()
    for filename in os.listdir("temp"):
        temp_files_list.append(f'{os.getcwd()}\\temp\\{filename}')
    for f in enumerate(temp_files_list):
        files[f"random-name-{f[0]}"] = open(f[1], "rb")
        if f[0] == 0:
            media.append({"type": "photo",
                          "media": f"attach://random-name-{f[0]}",
                          "caption": text}
                         )
        else:
            media.append({"type": "photo",
                          "media": f"attach://random-name-{f[0]}"})
    params = {
        "chat_id": chat_id, "media": str(media).replace("'", '"')}
    request_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + TOKEN + "/sendMediaGroup"
    result = requests.post(request_url, params=params, files=files)
    if result.status_code == 200:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ваш ответ не подходит к вопросу, зачем мне отправить группу, если я хочу получить группу фото которую отправили боту.

Answer (score -1):

Aiogram 3
https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/filters/magic_filters.html

```
@router.message(F.text.in_({'text1', 'text2', 'text3'}))
async def post_message_handler(msg: Message):
    print('Yes!')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]