# Нужно, чтобы бот принимал несколько фотографий от пользователей и пересылал их в отдельный чат в телеграмме (aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Самостоятельно смог реализовать прием только 1 фотографии через метод bot.send_photo, а нужно, чтобы бот мог принимать сразу несколько фотографий и пересылать их в отдельный чат

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получать несколько фото одним хендлером aiogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1394009/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%85%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-aiogram)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать машину состояний, после первой отправки бот будет ждать следующую и так далее.Кол-во фотографий будет зависеть от того сколько Вы сами зададите.

```
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemopyStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
        
        
storage = MemopyStorage()
# нужно передать в диспетчер Dispatcher(bot, storage =storage)
class GetImage(StatesGroup):
    image_1=State()
    image_2=State()
        
@dp.message_handler(commands=['add_image'],state=None)
async def get_photo(message : types.Message):
    await GetImage.image_1.set()
    await message.reply('Загрузи фото')
    
#обработчик выхода из машины состояний
@dp.message_handler(state='*', commands='отмена')
async def cancel_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if current_state is None:
        return
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer('Добавление фото отменено!')
        
        
@dp.message_handler(state=GetImage.image_1)
async def process_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['image_1'] = message.photo[0].file_id
    await GetImage.next()
    await message.reply('Загрузи следующее фото!')
        
@dp.message_handler(state=GetImage.image_2)
async def process_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['image_2'] = message.photo[0].file_id
    await state.finish()
    await message.reply('Все фото загружены')
```

Comment: А как потом выгрузить эти фотографии?

Comment: Все также с помощью await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.from_user, photo=image_1) прописываете в обработчике

Comment: Смотрите, имеется машина состояний, каждый стейт в ней - ответ на определенный вопрос пользователем. В конце все ответы автоматически пересылаются в отдельный чат, только загвоздка в том, что в конце я запрашиваю отправить фото у пользователя, а переслать вместе с другими ответами именно НЕСКОЛЬКО фотографий не знаю как. В примере, который указал tomato-magnet-regulato используются одни и те же фотографии для отправки их пользователям, а мне нужно, чтобы пользователь САМ отправлял свои фотографии, а бот пересылал их в отдельный чат с другими ответами

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить вам вариант использования `Media.Group()` недавно сам воспользовался, нужно было на входе получать альбом из фото и пересылать их в другой чат, чтобы это реализовать можете воспользоваться моим ответом из данного [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1444343/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-media-group)
Вот его код:

```
import asyncio
from typing import List, Union

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import CancelHandler
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware

bot = Bot(token="TOKEN_HERE")  # Place your token here
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


class AlbumMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    """This middleware is for capturing media groups."""

    album_data: dict = {}

    def __init__(self, latency: Union[int, float] = 0.01):
        """
        You can provide custom latency to make sure
        albums are handled properly in highload.
        """
        self.latency = latency
        super().__init__()

    async def on_process_message(self, message: types.Message, data: dict):
        if not message.media_group_id:
            return

        try:
            self.album_data[message.media_group_id].append(message)
            raise CancelHandler()  # Tell aiogram to cancel handler for this group element
        except KeyError:
            self.album_data[message.media_group_id] = [message]
            await asyncio.sleep(self.latency)

            message.conf["is_last"] = True
            data["album"] = self.album_data[message.media_group_id]

    async def on_post_process_message(self, message: types.Message, result: dict, data: dict):
        """Clean up after handling our album."""
        if message.media_group_id and message.conf.get("is_last"):
            del self.album_data[message.media_group_id]


@dp.message_handler(is_media_group=True, content_types=types.ContentType.ANY)
async def handle_albums(message: types.Message, album: List[types.Message]):
    """This handler will receive a complete album of any type."""
    media_group = types.MediaGroup()
    for obj in album:
        if obj.photo:
            file_id = obj.photo[-1].file_id
        else:
            file_id = obj[obj.content_type].file_id

        try:
            # We can also add a caption to each file by specifying `"caption": "text"`
            media_group.attach({"media": file_id, "type": obj.content_type})
        except ValueError:
            return await message.answer("This type of album is not supported by aiogram.")

    await message.answer_media_group(media_group)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dp.middleware.setup(AlbumMiddleware())
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Можете убрать одно из состояний и просто получать на одном состоянии все фото, которые требуются и отправлять их сразу группой в другой чат.
А для пересылки в другой чат сообщений можете использовать обычный метод `await bot.send_message` просто в качестве `chat_id` укажите `id` чата куда нужно что-то отправить, просто на нужном этапе записывайте в переменную и отправляйте.