# Как установить обратно, функцию None?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Подскажите, на одном сайте, мне сказали, что нужно устанавливать ему обратно None, но не напасили, как прописать код, как это сделать?

Мне нужно, чтобы на каждую публикация, с фото, отправлялся 1текст, без дублирования, по количеству фото.

Вот код, сейчас дублирования нет, но со 2-3 раза, при отправке, нескольких фото, без подписи, не реагирует и не пишет.

```
flag_group_id = None


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def inline_menu(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Добро пожаловать.')
    return


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo'])
async def get_message(message: types.Message):
    global flag_group_id

    if message.photo and not flag_group_id:
            flag_group_id = message.media_group_id
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Текст".format(message.from_user), parse_mode='html', disable_notification=True, disable_web_page_preview=True)
            return
```

Comment: Используйте этот способ для ловли группы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1443933/312230

Comment: Вы хоть, его проверяли?, я устанавливал и проверял, он не для этого, мне не нужно публиковать галерею фото, от имени бота, внимательно читайте вопрос.

Comment: Да я проверял, и уверен, что этот способ значительно эффективнее, чем тот что у вас. Особенно если учитывать что вы записываете айди группы в глобальную переменную, которая, при условии что еще один юзер отправит фото в то время когда это делает текущий, пойдет по 5 точке. Тот способ позволяет вам безопасно отлавливать группу даже если вы не намерены пересылать что-то куда-то.