# Выдает ошибку, когда пытаюсь получить нулевой элемент массива

Tags: python, aiogram

```
async def get_foto(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.photo:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            if type(data.get('photo')) is list:
                data['photo'].append(message.photo[-1].file_id)
                data["time"] = time()
                return
            else:
                data['photo'] = [message.photo[-1].file_id]
                data["time"] = time()
        wait_time = 3
        while time() - data["time"] < wait_time:
            await sleep(0.5)
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            poli = types.MediaGroup()
            for i in data['photo']:
                poli.attach_photo(photo=i)
            if data.get('time'):
                del data["time"]
            del data["photo"]
    elif message.video:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            if type(data.get('video')) is list:
                data['video'].append(message.video.file_id)
                data["time"] = time()
                return
            else:
                data['video'] = [message.video.file_id]
                data["time"] = time()
        wait_time = 3
        while time() - data["time"] < wait_time:
            await sleep(0.5)
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            poli = types.MediaGroup()
            for i in data['video']:
                poli.attach_video(video=i)
            if data.get('time'):
                del data["time"]
            del data["video"]
    if message.caption:
        print(poli)
        print()
        print(poli[0])
```

При `print(poli[0])` выдает `return self.values[item] KeyError: 0`
Что за фигня?

Comment: А что печатает `print(poli)` выше? Может у вас там не список, а словарь, например? Или ещё что-то.

Comment: Попробуйте так `print(poli.media[0])`, судя по коду в https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/7eb32785f6c8bbc464eea5233bd3ea84cd645fb1/aiogram/types/input_media.py#L245, это должно сработать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1443933/312230 используйте этот способ для ловли медиагруппы, ибо ваш (мой старый) код это ужас.