# Как получать несколько фото в одном хендлере Aiogram 3

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Аналог [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1394009/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-aiogram) вопроса для 3-ой версии Aiogram, так как были большие изменения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Делаем мидлварь

```
import asyncio
from typing import Callable, Any, Awaitable, Union

from aiogram import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import Message


class SomeMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    album_data: dict = {}

    def __init__(self, latency: Union[int, float] = 0.01):
        self.latency = latency

    async def __call__(
            self,
            handler: Callable[[Message, dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]],
            message: Message,
            data: dict[str, Any]
    ) -> Any:
        if not message.media_group_id:
            await handler(message, data)
            return
        try:
            self.album_data[message.media_group_id].append(message)
        except KeyError:
            self.album_data[message.media_group_id] = [message]
            await asyncio.sleep(self.latency)

            data['_is_last'] = True
            data["album"] = self.album_data[message.media_group_id]
            await handler(message, data)

        if message.media_group_id and data.get("_is_last"):
            del self.album_data[message.media_group_id]
            del data['_is_last']
```

##### регистрируем её до регистрации хендлеров

```
dp.message.middleware(SomeMiddleware())
```

##### применяем

```
from aiogram import F
from aiogram.types import Message, InputMediaPhoto, InputMedia, ContentType as CT

# пример отправки тех же данных в виде медиагруппы
@dp.message(F.content_type.in_([CT.PHOTO, CT.VIDEO, CT.AUDIO, CT.DOCUMENT]))
async def handle_albums(message: Message, album: list[Message]):
    media_group = []
    for msg in album:
        if msg.photo:
            file_id = msg.photo[-1].file_id
            media_group.append(InputMediaPhoto(media=file_id))
        else:
            obj_dict = msg.dict()
            file_id = obj_dict[msg.content_type]['file_id']
            media_group.append(InputMedia(media=file_id))

    await message.answer_media_group(media_group)
```