# Как принять несколько фото от пользователя в одном сообщении?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть бот который принимает одно фото от пользователя. Как принять от пользователя несколько фото? То есть в одном сообщение может быть n фотографий и после этого переслать это сообщение в закрытую группу. Можна ли такое вобще сделать? Как узнать что пользователь прислал больше одного фото? И можна ли принимать несколько документов в одном сообщении(pdf, doc, и тд)?

```
@rate_limit(0.5)
@dp.message_handler(IsPrivate(), content_types=['any'])
async def get_message(message: types.Message, album: List[types.Message]):
    if bool(album):
        media_group = types.MediaGroup()
        for obj in album:
            if obj.photo:
                file_id = obj.photo[-1].file_id
            else:
                file_id = obj[obj.content_type].file_id
            try:
                media_group.attach({"media": file_id, "type": obj.content_type})
            except ValueError:
                return await message.answer("This type of album is not supported by aiogram.")
        await bot.send_media_group(private_group, media_group)
    elif message.photo:
        information_the_user = ''
        caption = ''
        if message.caption is not None:
            caption += f'{message.caption}\n\n'
        if message.from_user.last_name is not None:
            information_the_user += f'<b>Last_name: {message.from_user.last_name}</b>\n'
        if message.from_user.username is not None:
            information_the_user += f'<b>Username: @{message.from_user.username}</b>\n'
        await bot.send_photo(private_group, photo=message.photo[-1].file_id,
                             caption=f'{caption}'
                                     f'<b>First_name: {message.from_user.first_name}</b>\n'
                                     f'{information_the_user}'
                                     f'<b>id: {message.from_user.id}</b>')
        data_id.add_message_id(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получать несколько фото в одном хендлере Aiogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1394009/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%85%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-aiogram)

Comment: @oleksandrigo Код с источника который Вы прислали работает, только проблема следующая. Первое когда присылаем одно фото выводиться ошибка. Второе у метода send_media_group нету caption.

Comment: Насчет caption он есть и как его юзать написано в комментарии `media_group.attach({"media": file_id, "type": obj.content_type, "caption": "text"})`. Ошибку же легко обойти просто делая проверку типа `if album:`

Comment: @oleksandrigo Я пробовал этот caption он не работает. Насчет проверки здесь посложнее я принимаю любой тип сообщения в одном хендлере и хочу там принимать альбом если его прислали.

Comment: Альбом у вас будет только в случае если вам прислали группу, потому вам нужна эта проверка

Comment: @oleksandrigo Я добавил проверку через bool но она не работает. Если присылаем одно фото появляеться ошибка что второго параметра нету. А когда присылаем группу фото, приходит только одно фото.

Comment: @oleksandrigo У меня еще такой вопрос я хочу получить id сообщения альбома я пробовал через message.message_id но там чем больше фото тем id становиться больше на 1, потом пробовал через media_group_id, там id сообщений каждый раз меняеться и невозможно отследить его. Ну и еще пробовал достать id пользователя в caption который передаю информаю про пользователя `str(message.reply_to_message.caption).split() ` и в результате возвращает пустой список. Как можна достать id сообщения(если прислали альбом) или вытянуть id с caption?

Comment: Ну так они и будут меняться, они же разные, хоть и группа

Comment: @oleksandrigo Да, но почему caption пустой? Если в него я добавляю информацию. Есть способ отловить id что б он совпадал в бд и закрытой групппе?

Comment: Дам вам совет, импортируйте модуль `import pprint from pprint` и сделайте принт всего альбома. Так вы будете видеть что у вас и где. Вы и caption найдете и всё что вам нужно

Comment: @oleksandrigo Да caption есть он привязан к последному фото `pprint(media_group.media[-1]["caption"])` Но когда я делаю reply на это сообщение в закрытой группе такое я сделать не могу. Потому что все что мне доступно из media это `message.reply_to_message.media_group_id`. Если взять `pprint(message.reply_to_message)` caption там нету

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте

```
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import CancelHandler
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import InputMedia

import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())


class AlbumMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    """This middleware is for capturing media groups."""

    album_data: dict = {}

    def __init__(self, latency: int | float = 0.01):
        """
        You can provide custom latency to make sure
        albums are handled properly in highload.
        """
        self.latency = latency
        super().__init__()

    async def on_process_message(self, message: types.Message, data: dict):
        if not message.media_group_id:
            return

        try:
            self.album_data[message.media_group_id].append(message)
            raise CancelHandler()  # Tell aiogram to cancel handler for this group element
        except KeyError:
            self.album_data[message.media_group_id] = [message]
            await asyncio.sleep(self.latency)

            message.conf["is_last"] = True
            data["album"] = self.album_data[message.media_group_id]

    async def on_post_process_message(self, message: types.Message, result: dict, data: dict):
        """Clean up after handling our album."""
        if message.media_group_id and message.conf.get("is_last"):
            del self.album_data[message.media_group_id]


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'audio', 'video', 'document'])
async def get_message(message: types.Message, album: list[types.Message] = None):
    if not album:
        album = [message]

    media_group = types.MediaGroup()
    for obj in album:
        if obj.photo:
            file_id = obj.photo[-1].file_id
        else:
            file_id = obj[obj.content_type].file_id
        try:
            if obj == album[-1]:
                media_group.attach(InputMedia(media=file_id,
                                              type=obj.content_type,
                                              caption=f'{album[0].caption}'
                                                      f'<b>First_name: {message.from_user.first_name}</b>\n'
                                                      # f'{information_the_user}'
                                                      f'<b>id: {message.from_user.id}</b>',
                                              parse_mode="html"))
            else:
                media_group.attach(InputMedia(media=file_id, type=obj.content_type))
        except ValueError:
            return await message.answer("This type of album is not supported by aiogram.")

    await bot.send_media_group(message.chat.id, media_group)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp.middleware.setup(AlbumMiddleware())
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Не работает. Присылает только одно одно фото, группу нет. Для альбома нужно делать отдельный хендлер? Я в get_message еще принимаю gif, текст(message.animation, message.text). И нужен ли для альбома мидлвари? Я пробовал с мидлвари и без, и всеравно не работает.

Comment: @Kanashii12 полностью рабочий код, проверял лично