# Добавление описание к альбому aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

Сделал получение и отправку альбома как в этом вопросе: [Как получать несколько фото в одном хендлере Aiogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1394009/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-aiogram)

Там есть добавление описания к каждой фотографии альбома, как можно добавить описание только к одному фото, что бы его было видно не заходя в фото?

Answer (score 0):

У telethon есть удобные инструменты работы как и с одиночными медиа файлами(не только фото, но и видео которые сгруппированы в альбом)

Например:

```
@client.on(events.Album(chats=[id_chanel]))
async def normal_handler(event):
  text2 = event.original_update.message.message
  await client.send_message(id_chanel, file=event.messages, message=text2)
```

Подробнее документация для [Telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/)